# RTP live stream from browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to record video/audio in a browser and push it to an RTP server.

From what I understand, doing this with RTMP, which is how we do it using OBS, is not going to happen?

From what I found, there's some degree of support for WebRTC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) and that it has *something* to do with RTP, but I'm not quite sure what?

I haven't been able to find anything, really, which is making me think maybe this just isn't feasible?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/akoidan/pychat and live demo https://pychat.org you can find some live examples there

Comment: I'm not understanding, why can't you use OBS?

Comment: Thanks @deathangel908 taking a look now

Comment: @fyroc I'm trying to build a way for users to push into our streaming infrastructure. Currently we use OBS, we want to enable them to stream directly from the browser

Comment: Oh sorry @deathangel908 - I'm not looking for a server component here. I have a whole infrastructure set up for streams, I'm just trying to find a way to get our users out of OBS and into the browser instead :)

Comment: Look at chrome extensions similar to:
https://studio.golightstream.com/welcome

Comment: Thank you but also not looking for any chrome extensions sorry!

Looking for a way to just bake this into our website, user comes in, click's go and they're live

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The idea of lightstream is similar, but they needed to use a browser extension. You have to encode the video in order to pass it to the RTMP server and that's not really possible with what you're looking for.

Comment: @RichardTaylor In my example, there's no server support for streaming, only the client one (browser with webrtc)